# windows vc++ how to use UniversalCRT_IncludePath and How to make it work in cl.exe

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, cl, vcbuild

I use windows 10 as test server and try to build from source code of python & C++.
I installed vcbuild 2015 by choco [choco windows package manager](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcbuildtools)

When I try to build the source, I find error.

```
E:\downloads\Twisted-17.1.0>cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -IC:\Python36\include -IC:\Python36\include /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
raiser.c

c:\python36\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

I can not find the io.h in my vc++ include path：
But according to the passage: [Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/)

I find the io.h file is in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt

Then I find my Universal CRT is empty

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set UniversalCRT_IncludePath
Environment variable UniversalCRT_IncludePath not defined
```

Then I define that envirnoment variable:

```
E:\downloads\Twisted-17.1.0> set UniversalCRT_IncludePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt"
```

Then I try to compile the source code again, but I still get an error:

```
E:\downloads\Twisted-17.1.0>cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -IC:\Python36\include -IC:\Python36\include /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
raiser.c

c:\python36\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

Anyone know how to make the UniversalCRT_IncludePath works in command line environment, how cl.exe try to use that variable and make it including default c++ including path.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That is not duplicated, my question is about UniveersalCRT_IncludePath

Comment: My mistake, sorry.

Comment: If you use the Developer Command Prompt shortcut, the directory in question is listed in the `INCLUDE` environment variable.  If you're setting up your environment by hand, you can presumably do the same thing, or list the directory as a command-line argument as Ben suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about `UniversalCRT_IncludePath` to `cl.exe`.

An MSBuild variable by that name (not the same as an environment variable or a shell variable) is used by the New-Project Wizard templates for Universal CRT to calculate the command-line to pass to `cl.exe`.

Because you're invoking the compiler by hand, you should just add a `/I` switch with that directory and not bother with any environment variable that the compiler doesn't look for anyway.